# Build aosp on mac 10.12

Tags: android-source

I used to build aosp on my mac. Recently I upgraded the mac os Mac Sierra (10.12). The I received this error message while building the project:

Could not find a supported mac sdk: ["10.8" "10.9" "10.10" "10.11"]

The mac sdk version has been upgraded to 10.12 however it is not within the supported mac sdk list. What could be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this problem on macOS Sierra (10.12.2) with Xcode 8.2. The solution may be helpful:

1. Download MacOSX10.11.sdk on [phracker/MacOSX-SDKs](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs)
2. Unzip to folder:  **/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/**

If you upgrade Xcode, the folder will be removed. So You will repeat the above action, or place it in your own directory then make a link.

Comment: adding the version in `core/combo/mac_version.mk` allowed me on `Sierra` to compile `Marshmallow`.

Answer (score 5):

man,here is  a good news .I find the error message source and find the method to solve it.Edit the file which location is android/build/soong/cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go .

```
darwinSupportedSdkVersions = []string{
    "10.8",
    "10.9",
    "10.10",
    "10.11",
    "10.12"
}
```

change it .

Answer (score 3):

I've never tried this on Sierra, but did run into the same issue on OS X El Capitan. Here's a link to my solution: [Running AOSP build on Mac (Yosemite and later)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589866/running-aosp-build-on-mac-yosemite-and-later/36709862#36709862) (worked for me). Gist of this is to get an older version of the XCode DMG, and dynamically mount it prior to building AOSP.

Here are a couple of threads talking about this same issue:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/BQHmUOmLq4I
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/vhnftES4MN8
- [Running AOSP build on Mac (Yosemite and later)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31589866/562139)

Good luck.

Comment: I've done the same thing (On El Capitan) and it worked for me using Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: This does work on Sierra. However it messes up with other things. We have to switch back and forth from 5.1.1 SDK to the latest one, e.g. for homebrew.

Comment: Harveys answer now solve this issue! No more back-n-forth between XCode versions!

Answer (score 3):

To build Android on MacBookPro High Sierra, I had to overcome few obstacles.

I looked up the MacOS SDK version, I am currently running:

```
$ ls /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/
MacOSX.sdk  MacOSX10.13.sdk
```

Then changed **build/soong/cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go** to:

```
darwinSupportedSdkVersions = []string{
    "10.8",
    "10.9",
    "10.10",
    "10.11",
    "10.12",
    "10.13",
}
```

I also had to get a **case-sensitive file system** USB-C SSD disk.

```
build/core/main.mk:105: warning: 
Please move your source tree to a case-sensitive filesystem.
```