# Could not find a supported mac sdk: ["10.10" "10.11" "10.12" "10.13"]

Tags: makefile, android-source

I see the error when I try to build Android Open Project Source .

```
ninja: no work to do.
[1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp

internal error: Could not find a supported mac sdk: ["10.10" "10.11" "10.12" "10.13"]

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
20:17:47 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (13 seconds) ####
```

my system version :

`macOS High Sierra v10.13.4`

my Xcode version:

`Version 9.3 (9E145)`

Can anyone help me ?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218532/9265308) ， but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
/Volumes/android/build/soong/cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go
```

please edit this file to include your version of SDK

```
darwinSupportedSdkVersions = []string{
        "10.10",
        "10.11",
        "10.12",
        "10.13",
```

or your version of mac sdk

Answer (score 6):

Expanding slightly on Krishna Chetan's answer:

```
# What mac sdk do you have installed?
find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs -iname "*.sdk"

# edit the configuration file
subl /<your Android build dir>/build/soong/cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go

# add your version to the listed versions in the file
darwinSupportedSdkVersions = []string{
        "10.10",
        "10.11",
        "10.12",
        "10.14", <--- add your version that you turned up in the find command here
    }
```

This worked for me on:

- Mac High Sierra Version 10.13.6 (17G3025)
- XCode Version 10.1 (10B61)

Answer (score 1):

- Download any of the 10.10,
      10.11,
      10.12,
      10.13 freaky Mac SDK sdk 10,1 from 
  https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs

  or https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases
- Copy and paste downloaded sdk in
  Finder--> Go To Folder-->

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs

[image]