# Error in compiling android (12) aosp on mac 13.3 m1 max

Tags: macos, sdk, android-source, apple-silicon

Google does not officially support compiling Android on Mac.
but I read that it is possible.

The command `m` has an error

How can I fix the error?

the error:

`"Could not find a supported mac sdk: [\"10.10\" \"10.11\" \"10.12\" \"10.13\" \"10.14\" \"10.15\" \"11.0\" \"11.1\"]"`

I understood that the problem is due to an incompatible sdk, in the guides I saw that you need to download a compatible sdk from https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases, but I can't find one for mac 13.3

**update:**
I added my sdk number to the array,
As in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715111/9458132.
And now there are errors:

`'sprintf' is deprecated: This function is provided for compatibility reasons only. Due to security concerns inherent in the design of sprintf(3), it is highly recommended that you use snprintf(3) instead. [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]`

I tried to fix it in the code(Although of course this is not a recommended thing...) , in any case there is an error:

```
`ld: in /Volumes/aosp/source/prebuilts/rust/darwin-x86/1.51.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-6c9932b2c088cadd.rlib(lib.rmeta), archive member 'lib. rmeta' with length 30728 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode file '/Volumes/aosp/source/prebuilts/rust/darwin-x86/1.51.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-6c9932b2c088cadd. rlib'
           clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: aborting due to previous error

15:15:09 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

1. Why there is the error
2. Is there a solution where they won't have to change the code (it turns out that because the sdk is not compatible, it also gets stuck afterwards..)

i am using mac 13.3 (ventura)

sdk version:
`13.3`
clang version:
`16.0.1`
thank's.

Comment: let me know if you are able to compile the images succesfully. Because I am trying something similar with A13, however no success even with make completed successfully -nothing to do.

Comment: Added comments for sprintf

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I was trying something similar, the solution to this answer is actually add your current macOS SDK to `darwinSupportedSdkVersions` in `cc/config/x86_darwin_host.go` like here, https://github.com/rajatgupta1998/build_soong/commit/845c27d520c601b71565d7754c6e2efb541414f4.

You can find the exact version number of the sdk installed on your system via this command:
`find /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs -iname "*.sdk"`

Another answer which explains this too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53715111/9458132

Update: For the `sprintf` deprecation issue, you can actually fix it by replacing with `snprintf` accordingly, since on Xcode 14+, sprintf is deprecated on mac. There are a few repos which require this patching.

Comment: error:
`ld: in /Volumes/aosp/source/prebuilts/rust/darwin-x86/1.51.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-6c9932b2c088cadd.rlib(lib.rmeta), archive member 'lib. rmeta' with length 30728 is not mach-o or llvm bitcode file '/Volumes/aosp/source/prebuilts/rust/darwin-x86/1.51.0/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunwind-6c9932b2c088cadd. rlib'
           clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Okay this seems a new one, I have not seen this on Android 13 or 11. What is the clang version and the sdk version you have installed? Can u share the versions in a comment here? Meanwhile I will be syncing AOSP 12 and trying this again.

Comment: clang 16.0.1 
sdk 13.3
[screenshot command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7aU.png)

Comment: p.s. There is an option to downgrade Clang? (When I tried to change the SDK to an older version, I encountered errors caused by Clang. I think this is because I also need to use an older version of Clang.)

Comment: hello. 

 @RajatGupta something new?
Could you detail what you were able to compile and on which version of mac, sdk, clang?

Answer (score 0):

You can by-pass the sprintf error, by adding those to lines into the file x86_darwin_host.go ( Path: build/soong/cc/config )

"-Wno-deprecated-declarations",
"-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types",
in the darwinCFlags section of the file